# Can I exclude operations from the undo stack in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function which reads notes from one sheet and writes them into cells in another sheet whenever an edit is made. However, whenever I do this, it adds all those writes to the undo stack. This means that whenever the user makes and edit, it's no longer possible to use the undo feature, as the undo stack is full of the edits the script has made.

Is there a way to exclude the write functions that the script does from the undo stack? I appreciate this may not be possible, but if I can't do that I'll have to do an hourly run using the timer, and this means everything will be up to an hour out of date.

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: Unsure what you are trying to do. I can see no correlation between edits being in the undo stack and the data being out of date unless someone keeps actively undoing everything.

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because it doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, but I have been looking into it and couldn't find an answer anywhere on the google apps script help pages or forums - hence this post. Do you have any better avenues to research?

Sorry @Vytaustas - that last sentence was confusing. At the moment, my function runs in the OnEdit(e) method, which means it runs every time an edit is made to the spreadsheet. Unfortunately, this puts the script changes made to the sheet into the undo stack, rather than the user edit being the last one in the stack, which would allow the user to undo their last action. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, the operation the script does is equivalent to you writing something in a cell yourself. The edit stack is tracked on the Sheet side and the edits are made by the user running the script.

Your only hope would be to run it as a different user than the one that has opened the spreadsheet, but that may not be possible given the nature of `onEdit()` triggers. See the trigger [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

The reason I suggest this is that sheets tracks each users edits separately. However even this is not a perfect solution as if we both edit the exact same cell, my undo will still change whatever your edits were. E.G if I write `A` into an empty cell, and you then write `B` into that same cell, one I hit undo, it will be an empty cell again.

Comment: Thanks for your succinct analysis... I feared this might be the case... I might have to see if I can ammend my script so it does something like updating all the cells at the same time (perhaps 'pasting' a group of cells in one go) which would leave me with a 2 tap kind of soultion on the undo button...

Comment: Not only to alleviate that problem, you should always look to output as much data at once as possible. Always try to use `.setValues()` instead of multiple `.setValue()` one row after another by creating an array of data first