# Why is Undo triggering my onEdit(), when the function is restricted to a specific column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this onEdit() function restricted to modifications in the first column of certain sheet. My problem is that when I press 'undo' or 'Ctrl + Z' outside the onEdit() range, the 'undo' triggers the function and clear some rows with the .clearContent().

Why is 'undo' doing this? I'm not modifying the first column. The log looks like this:

```
[18-10-03 10:41:09:166 VET] onEdit
[18-10-03 10:41:09:167 VET] event {authMode=LIMITED, range=Range, source=Spreadsheet, user=name.lastname@company.com}   -   A3:A22   -  true
```

This is my function:

```
function onEdit(e){

  init()

  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == htSheet.getName()) {
    if ((e.range.getColumn() == 1) && (e.range.getRow() >= StartRowHT) && (typeof e.value == "string")){
      Logger.log("fired")
      onSelectTask(e)
    } else if ((e.range.getColumn() == 1) && (typeof e.value != "string")){
      //clean row

      var rowIndex = e.range.getRow()

      range1 = "B" + rowIndex + ":G"  + rowIndex
      range2 = "I" + rowIndex + ":ZZ" + rowIndex

      htSheet.getRangeList([range1, range2]).clearContent()
    }
    Logger.log("onEdit")
    Logger.log("event %s   -   %s   -  %s", e, e.range.getA1Notation(), typeof e.value != "string")
  }
}

function init() {
  taskRange = htSheet.getRange(StartRowHT, 1,  (calendar.getLastRow() - StartRowCal + 1))

  var rule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sheetname.getRange("H4:H1000"), true).build()

  taskRange.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The log statements (and your `init()` call) are before your code guards...

Comment: Okay I will make a log after

Comment: @tehhowch I placed the log at the end and the result is the same.

Comment: If the `log` and `init()` statements are not *inside the code guards* (like your "fired" log message), then they will always execute when the edit trigger is activated.

Comment: @tehhowch Even if the event is an 'Undo' inside Google Spreadsheet? I'll check it out.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995333/can-i-exclude-operations-from-the-undo-stack-in-google-apps-script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931041/undo-redo-of-google-apps-script-execution

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your replies.